# Preserving page margins in openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am able to set page margins on a worksheet and then, say, export it to a pdf with the proper page margins. The page margins are properly saved and show up as expected in Excel. However, if I re-open the workbook with openpyxl, the page margins revert to their defaults. Is there a way to preserve the existing page margins when loading a workbook?

What I've done:

```
import openpyxl
f = 'Test.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

ws.page_margins.left = 3
print ws.page_margins.left

wb.save(f)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print ws.page_margins.left
```

This code from above prints:

```
3.0
0.75
```

when I'm expecting to see:

```
3.0
3.0
```

Comment: This is a known issue with 2.3.0 and has been fixed in https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/88/

Comment: Charlie, I'm having the same issue with print titles (after using add_print_title) not being retained on subsequent loads. Would you be able to point to where in the source I might be able to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Print titles are a whole different item as they are stored as constants. Currently we drop them with a warning. The whole definedName code is scheduled for a rewrite to be more reliable.